# How to make a connection to Parse via requests instead of httplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, parse-platform, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a custom endpoint I've set up on [Parse Cloud Code](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide). In the docs they show how to make a connection:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/functions/userData', json.dumps({
        "userID": "1234"
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "####",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "####",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

This work great.

I'm trying to write it with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) but I continually get a 404:

```
import json, requests

PARSE_HOSTNAME = 'https://api.parse.com:443'
PARSE_APP_ID = '####'
PARSE_REST_API_KEY = '####'


endpoint = '/1/function/userData/'
headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_APP_ID, 
           "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "PARSE_REST_API_KEY", 
           "Content-Type": "application/json"}
payload = {'userID': '1234'}

r = requests.post(PARSE_HOSTNAME + endpoint, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print r.json
```

Which prints out:

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [404]>>
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. Sorry for the ignorance.
How do I accomplish the same result as the first but with requests?

Comment: to call a method in Python, add parens `()` e.g., `r.json()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URL misspelling in the second example. You have

```
/1/function/userData/
```

must be

```
/1/functions/userData
```